# Is there a way to work around FortiClient blocking the deletion of binded folders on Docker when running pipelines from Azure DevOps?

Tags: windows, docker, powershell, forticlient

I have a problem with forticlient (version 7.0.3.0193) installed on Windows Server 2019, basically when pipelines are run from azure devops that launches a docker container, forticlient blocks the ability to delete folders used as binded folders on docker and until i'll shut down forticlient completely ( even have to unplug it from the ems) it keeps using the resource, blocking it's deletion.

I had tried to create an ad hoc policy for this server disabling every rule or excluding scanning binded paths.
I also tried to run the same commands manually but nothing changed.

What could be the cause? There is a solution?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.